# What new APIs should W3C work in to allow powerful mobile web applications?

Tags: html, mobile-website

As an amateur mobile developer, I feel dismay every time I have to fix, update or add new features to an application of mine.

I'm eagerly awaiting the moment you can just develop a web application for any kind of device.

HTML5 and new APIs like Geolocation API or [Contacts API](http://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/) are a step forward, but what other APIs could be useful to move current mobile developers to the web? For example, some kind of Sensor API to access mobile accelerometers or magnetometers.

I am aware that future Flash and AIR mobile releases are coming, but I'd rather prefer web standards.

Comment: “As an amateur mobile developer, I feel dismay every time I have to fix, update or add new features to an application of mine.” — Really? Which part of amateur development do you actually *enjoy* then?

Comment: The one before any user actually uses the app ;-)

Comment: Software would work much more reliably if it wasn’t for the users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s an idea to add a general devices API to HTML5.

http://www.w3.org/TR/dap-api-reqs/

To be honest, I don’t think you can do this sort of thing generically (or at least it’s an impractical challenge). I think it’s down to the folks who make mobile operating systems — i.e. Apple, Google, and the rest — decide whether and how to provide JavaScript access to hardware.

It’s potentially a massive security risk. Go to a hijacked website, and suddenly Russian criminals are copying every photo you take? There’s a “powerful mobile web application” for you.

Comment: Well, I agree that security is a serious concern here. But you take the same risks when installing applications from the Android store, for example. It's all about trust and precaution.

Comment: And you don’t take the same risks when installing from the App Store, because Apple reviews those apps. Hence why I doubt this kind of thing can be standardised.